# Why won't my Hapi backend serve static files with dynamic file names?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I am currently adding new features to a rather big project which has been running for a couple of years. The project uses a Couch DB database, Hapijs in the backend and React in the frontend.

My goal is to add a download button that let's the user (admin) download all the .pdf files from the database sorted by year and bundled in a .zip archive. The server already has a route for similar tasks, which is why I'm expanding the functionality of this route instead of creating a new one from scratch.

The `/generate/{query}` route handles all the file exports depending on the params in the query string. The query params will always contain the year. The route starts like this:

```js
 server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/generate/{query*}',

    handler: async function(request, h) {
      ...
      }
     })
```

This route starts a long series of asynchronous processes and in the end successfully stores all the .pdf files in a tmp folder, sorted by year and bundled in .zip files. The only thing left to do would be to send the .zip file as a response back to the frontend, where the download is triggered.

This is where I'm having problems:

I am using the inert package to add files to my response with the `file()` method. If I pass in the path as a hardcoded string (e.g. `file('/tmp/2019.zip')`), the data is sent to the frontend correctly and the download starts as it should. However, if I try to build the same string dynamically, I get a corrupted .zip file that's only 1MB - 3MB (the original file is 250MB) (once it was 80MB, once 150MB, but both files were corrupted and couldn't be unpacked). I have tried a couple of different approaches to get a dynamic file path (template literals etc.), but they all produced the same result. This is what I'm currently stuck with:

```js
            const response = h.file(Path.join(__dirname + '/tmp/' + request.query.year + '.zip'), {
              mode: 'attachment',
          })
             return response
```

I then created the following test route:

```js
  server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/test/{query*}',
      handler: function(req, res) {
        return res.file(Path.join(__dirname + '/tmp/' + req.query.year + '.zip'), {
          mode: 'attachment'
      })
      }
  })
```

...and it works like a charm, no matter which year I pass in as a query param.

This makes it difficult to pinpoint the exact part of my code that causes trouble: there are no issues with dynamically generated file paths in my test route, so that can't be it. The code in the actual route is also executed correctly, but only if the path to the file is hardcoded, so it's obviously not completely broken. For testing purposes I am currently not removing files from the tmp folder, so it can't be a problem with my async functions (the differently sized corrupted .zip files made me wonder if this might have something to do with my problem). But... what else could it be? Why can't I pass dynamic file names in my main route?

Has anybody here ever encountered anything like this? Let me know if you need more details. Any help is appreciated, even the slightest hunch could be of help!